# Dynamic formula with quotes inside a COUNTIFS function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, countif, excel-indirect

I am trying to adapt the following formula (counting instances of values between 0 and 24):

```
=COUNTIFS(cancellations!AG2:AG408,">0",cancellations!AG2:AG408,"<24")
```

(formula evaluates to 75), to something like:

```
=COUNTIFS(cancellations!AG2:AG408,">0",cancellations!AG2:AG408,INDIRECT("" & "<" & B1*24 & ""))
```

but this evaluates to zero. (B1 = 1 in the above example.)

When I view the INDIRECT function inside the fx box it evaluates correctly. Not sure of what I am doing wrong.

When applied in a cell like so:

```
=INDIRECT("" & "<" & B1*24 & "")
```

It shows `#REF!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [INDIRECT function](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html) returns a reference to a range. You can use this function to create a reference that won't change if row or columns are inserted in the worksheet. Or, use it to create a reference from letters and numbers in other cells.

```
=COUNTIFS(cancellations!AG2:AG408,">0",cancellations!AG2:AG408,B1)
```

should work where B1 contains `<24`.

Answer (score 1):

So, I read up the COUNTIFS() function in more detail and I found that the following works

```
=COUNTIFS(cancellations!AG2:AG408,">0",cancellations!AG2:AG408,"<"&B1*24)
```

Where:
    B1=1